# How to enable comments and likes for my posts made with my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

When my Facebook app posts to the users stream those posts do not get links for Like and Comment. Other Facebook publishing apps, like Instagram, get these links.

I can't find it in my Facebook application's settings. Anyone knows how to do it?

(I think this is the same question as this one: [Facebook : Like and Comment Functionality against Wall Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157612/facebook-like-and-comment-functionality-against-wall-post) but I'm not sure.)

See [Traroth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505714/traroth) comment to get a more to the point description of what it is I'm asking about.

Comment: I'm not completly sure what you're meaning. Your application add updates to the user's wall on Facebook, and these updates cannot be commented of liked? Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: How are you creating the posts? The like and comment buttons are their by default and are controlled by facebook.

Comment: I use the Graph API and am POSTing to the path "me/feed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [Nathat Totten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75505/nathan-totten) is right about how these links are defaults and that they are controlled by Facebook. There are three things that confuses this issue.

One is that Facebook Test Users behave a bit more special than you might think. Even when they are friends, they are not fully so. Making these default links turn up only for the user that posts them (for Test Users, mind you, I'm hoping it'll work all right for real users).

Another is the documentation for `actions` in the [Facebook Graph API documentation for publishing Post objects](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post):

> A list of available actions on the post (including commenting, liking, and an optional app-specified action). read_stream. A list of JSON objects containing the 'name' and 'link'.

Which made me start to try find out how to include the commenting and liking links myself. I can't find this info anywhere, so maybe that changed without the above quoted documentation reflecting the change.

Anyway, if, indeed this is a Test User issue, then I don't need to do anything special to fix this. I'll try to remember to come back here when my (iPhone) app is ready for the real Facebook world and I get to see if it works in that environment or not.